# Get Icon by Proccess Handle and Display it

Tags: c#, wpf, image, icons

I have a list of all opened applications shown in the taskbar.
Every item in the list hold the application/proccess Title and Handle (hWnd).

First, I would like to get the proccess Icon, so I used:

```
Icon ico = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(hWnd);
```

not sure if it works because I dont know how to display it.

So as you can understand, I want to display Icon in Image control, how can I do it? I tried to save in `memoryStream` and I also tried `.ToBitmap()` but I got exceptions.

Will appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: No, that doesn't work, FromHandle requires a handle to an icon, not a window.  You'll need to send the WM_GETICON message to the window by pinvoking SendMessage().  Then Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/12/18/find-an-applications-icon-with-winapi/ for WM_GETICON code sample.